# Playing SHOUTcast urls in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

Can anybody please give me a help of playing SHOUT cast urls like

```
http://38.101.195.5:8456

http://38.101.195.5:8056 in windows phone 8 using c#.net.
```

I have seen examples
 in this site.But even though I was not getting any idea of playing them.Anyone please give me help of playing shoutcast urls.
Thanking you in advance.

Comment: There's a commercial middleware for that. I did this http://const.me/SkyFM/technical.aspx and also there's http://www.apollosdk.com/ developed by some other people I don't know. I haven't heard about free alternatives.

Comment: Ya thankyou for your help.But I did not understand how to use it.Can you please tell me.Thanking you.

Comment: "Commercial middleware" means "you can't use until you buy the license".

Comment: k.Thankyou.It is a softwre we have to install?

Comment: You'll get a DLL containing MediaStreamSource implementation capable of playing the ShoutCast streams. If that's what you need, please e-mail me on soonts@live.com, and I'll happily give you more information about pricing and usage.

Comment: ya k got it.Thanyou for your explanation.